# Java - converting html with images in CSS to pdf

Tags: java, html, pdf

I am looking for a free java library to convert html to pdf. Html page is formatted with CSS, and those styles contains images (.gif). At the moment I am using Flying Saucer but this library cant convert CSS with images properly.
Thanks in advance.
Marek

Comment: Maybe HTML-tidy->xhtml+XSLT-XSLTEngine->XSL-FO-FO Engine->PDF? I'm not sure about the CSS support in tidy, you should try. Anything else would be for money only, I think...

Answer (score 0):

I use YAHP.

http://www.allcolor.org/YaHPConverter/

It does have CSS. I have had issues with some CSS styles, such as the roundborder ones specific to chrome/firefox, but it does have CSS. I can't remember ever having a problem with CSS images.

Comment: Thanks, Ill check if it converts those images :)

Comment: Unfortunatly YAHP is using flying saucer renderer and this renderer cant format my htmi page properly. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

one lame way (but hey you may be desperate)  is there is a java library for contacting openoffice running as a headless server. This is http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter ... and use openoffice to convert. OTOH, this is pretty kludgy, and definitely not pure java)  and I'm not sure how good the openoffice html import filter is ... but I guess it's worth looking at. There used to be some html to pdf converters built into iText but they have been removed (and were pretty limited).

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML to PDF converver: http://pd4ml.com/index.htm. It's writen purely in Java

Answer (score 0):

Try the Adobe -Generate PDF API (Java)-- http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/programLC/programmer/help/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=sdkHelp&file=000447.html - here you can see the how to, and at the bottom, a quickstart which contains working sample java code to convert a web page into PDF.

Answer (score 0):

[Prince XML](http://www.princexml.com/) is the best and easiest to use PDF generator I've used. A commercial license costs a pretty penny, but if you're OK with a small watermark on the first page of your document, the free version is great. It can be integrated with a number of programming languages, [including Java](http://www.princexml.com/doc/7.0/java/).